Suppress build-html errors in vite
Users of our application have introduced faulty HTML tags in our data. It seems that the pages with the errors still load properly in Chrome. However, when trying to run tsc && vite build, we encounter many errors due to these faulty tags. Since the pages still load, we'd like to just ignore them instead of fixing them all just to use vite. Is there a way to ignore these in vite?
Here is an example error:
error during build:
[vite:build-html] Unable to parse HTML; parse5 error code unexpected-character-in-attribute-name

I looked in the docs and through npx vite build --help but did not find a way to ignore these errors.
